# Compiz (?) crash when trying to see multiple windows of the same app

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, crash, taskbar

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 recently and the only problem I have right now is this glitch that doesn't let me see the other windows of the same app.

When I click the icon so it shows me all the windows I have of that app it just crashes the UI and restarts again.

How can I fix it? If it can't be solved I'll have to install Ubuntu again and/or downgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by CantankRus in [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2338035&p=13549148#post13549148) after me saying it just happened in my profile:

"...Suggests it's a user config error.
The unity window manager (compiz) handles the window spread function.

Log into your regular account and reset compiz to defaults with this terminal command...

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Log out and back in and test."